# Error 1004 when printing PDFs after upgrade to Office 2016

Tags: excel, pdf, excel-2016, vba

I have a workbook of ~50 worksheets. Code loops through every sheet, assigns title row, print area and pagebreaks on each sheet and after that prints PDF to specific folder. Code worked fine until last week, when I have updated my Office to 2016 (from Excel 2013).

I get error in part of the code which is repeated at every sheet, after ~25 PDFs are printed successfully (at same sheet by default, but when I suppress part of the code which prints this sheet, I get error on the next sheet). Error message appears in the line marked with **.

```
 Sub UpdatePDFs_Click()
   'some code which saves workbook to server location three times
        (first is copy of initial one, second is later opened & changed,
         and third one is for running code (deleted at the end))
   'code which opens second workbook (PDFbook) and make adjustments 
        (copying some sheets and deleting some content)
   'code which follows:

  PDFbook.Save
  PDFbook.Close True
  Set PDFbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Def_path & Dir_name & "\" & Filename2)
  Dim sht01 As Worksheet
    For Each sht01 In PDFbook.Worksheets
       If sht01.Name = "sheet1" Then
             sht01.Activate
             ' rows count & HPagebreaks
             FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlDown).Row ' number of rows to print
             PrintAreaAndHPageBreaks FinalRow ' subroutine which is repeated
             ' PDF print
             ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D" & FinalRow).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
             Filename:=Path_PDF & "SO-" & ActiveSheet.Range("A2") & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("B2") & "-sheet1", Quality:=xlQualityMinimal
             ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
       ElseIf sht01.Name = "sheet2" Then
              sht01.Activate

    'etc for all sheets which we want to print

               Else
               ' sht01.Delete
                End If
            Next sht01
    PDFbook.Close True

  ' close dummy
  MsgBox "PDFs were created sucessfully"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
    Kill strFile
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

 Sub PrintAreaAndHPageBreaks(FinalRow As Long)
  ' define print area
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
  ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
  With ActiveSheet
    .PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows(7).Address
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:D" & FinalRow
    .VPageBreaks.Add before:=Columns("D")
    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
  End With
    Dim NumHPB As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
    NumHPB = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count
  For j = 1 To NumHPB
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & 
   ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Item(j).Location.Row)
    If Rng.Value = "" Then
        For i = 1 To 200
            **If Rng.Offset(-(i), 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then**
                ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Rows(ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Item(j).Location.Row - i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```

I get error 1004, sometimes Excel restarts itself or [freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e17Ts.jpg). Result in the specified folder are the same: ~25 PDFs are printed successfully (to the loop where error arises in second Sub), then around 10 PDF have size of 5Kb, all others are missing.

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this error or what it is going on?

Comment: Have you verified that the references are the same from before the update?  Not saying it's the fix, but is an issue I have had to deal with when my company computer downgraded to 2016.

Comment: Cyril, thanks for the comment. I use three references - VB for Applications & Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library are the same in both cases. Reference Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library is in office 2016 updated to version 16.0. Can solution be to use late binding?